# Can I resolve the krogan / salarian conflict with both sides supporting the Alliance?

Tags: mass-effect-3

This question contains spoilers.

> I just finished Mass Effect 3 and I was able to keep both quarians and the geth for the final push. Since this conflict is the deepest (in my opinion) among all the other conflicts between races, so I was wondering whether I can cure the genophage and still earn the salarian's support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also gain both their support under specific circumstances.

1. Wreave must be alive instead of Wrex.
2. You had to destroy Maelon's data in ME2.

With Maelon's data destroyed Eve dies during the run towards the genophage distribution facility, you can then persuade Mordin that with Eve dead Wreave will have no one to control his krogan behavior and he will agree on faking the genophage cure. Wreave thinks he's cured, you get Krogan support. You didn't cure the genophage, you get Salarian support.

If Wrex is alive, the only way is by saving the council dude.

Either way is pretty heartbreaking, You either lose Wrex or you lose Thane or Kirrahe.

Comment: The only way to not loose Thane or Kirrahe is to have lost them both during the previous games, so it's not *that* bad.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can

> To do so, You have to cure the Genophage, and then save the salarian councillor. (Captain Kirrahe or Thane must be alive)

Comment: I saved the coundillor but nothing happened. I only got the STG's support.

Comment: You are supposed to have some fleat also.
Was your Wrex alive?

Comment: Yep. I imported my save from ME2 all of the guys were alive (except for Ashley, poor racist bastard died of a nuclear blast).

Comment: If you save the Salarian Councillor you get the war asset Salarian 3rd Fleet for 125 TMS.

Comment: But at the ending Joker did not say that the salarian fleet reported in.

Comment: had the same problem ... :/ any1 got an idea wy?

Answer (score 5):

spoilers

this is the total number of war assets from the Salarians:

```
125 from saving the Salarian councilor in me1 
35  for letting Kirahee die and talking to Lt. Tolen at the STG base in me3 
25  from Mordin if you persuade him that curing the genophage is a bad 
      idea with Wreav in charge and Eve dead 
150 from sabotaging the cure and 
8   from a Salarian side mission
= 343
```

You also get the Krogan too with this

```
25  from Wreav 
25  from Grunt if he survived me2 and his loyalty mission was completed 
50  from Arlak company 
50  from n7 Cerberus attack 
345 from Krogan clans and also speaking with Diana Allers 
40  from Krogan side mission 
300 Clan Urdnot 
=795
```

Add them together and you get a total war asset amount of 1138.

When you cure the genophage and lose the extra Salarian support, you get 875+169 which equals to 1044.

So kill Wrex and destroy Maelon's data. All it will do is change dialog, nothing bad.

Comment: Flagging this for deletion.  The lack of spelling, grammar and formatting make it a low quality answer.  This is is also a three year old question with an answer, and you haven't presented any new information.  Please think before necroing.

Comment: @sommerjj I fixed the grammar, spelling and formating problems. The question being old is irrelevant as long as it still applies to the game and the exact numbers are new information.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not going to kill Wrex in any of my walkthroughs because I like him and I *do not* like Wreav.

Answer (score 3):

You need Wrex alive for this and need to have saved the council, inform wrex of the Salarian Councillors duplicity and Mordin will say he can bypass the safety protocol to administer the cure. When you eventually save the Salarian councillour at the Citadel the Salarians will give you their full support in thanks (Hackett will tell you this in vidcom) unfortunately you still lose Thane :-( but its the way he would of wanted to go!!
RIP Thane

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get both their support with Wrex alive by not telling the Krogen about the sabotage  then choosing to shoot Mordin before he could fix it. It means you betrayed Wrex's trust but hey, he's still alive and you get both Krogen and Salarian support.

Comment: How devastated were you when Wrex confronted you after Rannoch?