# Mass effect 3 can you get the max war assets for krogan and salarian!]?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I resolve the krogan / salarian conflict with both sides supporting the Alliance?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56813/can-i-resolve-the-krogan-salarian-conflict-with-both-sides-supporting-the-alli)

Is there a way to get all of the war assets from salarain and krogan?